# I have a project and it is developed in php but now how can i convert it to laravel

Tags: php, laravel-5.4

I have a project and it is developed in php but now how can I convert it to laravel.
If I rename my php file to blade and if I create router and controller, is it enough or is there is different procedure.

Comment: I have an old nokia, will it become an Iphone if I stick an apple sticker at the back of it? Laravel is a full-sized framework, a migration in the end means that you have to rewrite the app, even if you can copy-paste some lines

Answer (score 0):

To do this you need to create a proper flow of your code and then need to create mvc structure in laravel.